# How can I interactively replace text in all files in all subfolders?

Tags: files, replace, query-replace-regexp

Emacs 27.1

Linux Mint 21

I have text **modifyNetwork** in 50 files in differents folders. I need to replace them by text **performCommand**.

What is the easiest way to replace text in all files in all subfolders?

Comment: Whatever method you use (in Emacs or not), you are going to have to specify the list of files on which to operate. That's not something that anybody here can give you any advice on, unless you say something more about what connects the 50 files together. If nothing, then you are going to have to make a list of those files manually. Once you've done that, the substitution is no problem (a `sed` as a comment in the answer indicates). But that's hardly an Emacs problem and therefore unsuitable for Emacs SE.

Comment: May be this helps: https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep and https://sachachua.com/blog/2021/08/using-the-wgrep-package-in-emacs-to-rewrite-grep-results-from-lots-of-files/

Comment: @OliverKnodel Yes, the rgrep + package wgrep are help me

Answer (score 3):

[18.20 Filesets](https://www.gnu.org/software//emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Filesets.html):

> If you regularly edit a certain group of files, you can define them as a *fileset*. This lets you perform certain operations, such as visiting, `query-replace`, and shell commands on all the files at once.

That's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If all your files belong to a single project, then `project-query-replace-regexp` is a solution. If they do not, you can use `sed`.

Comment: Reihs No this files not belongs to project.

Comment: Then I do not know any appropriate Emacs feature. But a shell script using `sed -i s/modifyNetwork/performCommand/` may do the job. @a_subscriber

Comment: [`multi-occur`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html) is a possibility. You will need a way to specify all the files that you want to operate on.